# Task Scheduler - Domain name in Logon trigger

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

Using Task Scheduler 2.0 (C#), and I need to create a task with a Logon trigger for a specific user. It's hard to believe that any of my users' machines are not part of a domain, but regardless, I wasn't comfortable writing something like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/trobbins/2006/01/04/retrieving-the-domain-name-and-host-name-with-vb-net/), without at least considering:

```cs
    logonTrigger.UserId = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName);
```

What surprised me though was that, if I set the `ILogonTrigger`'s `UserId` to only the `Environment.UserName`, without the domain name, it end up resolving to the correct domain automatically.

I'm wondering who's responsible for this, and is it safe enough to deploy this to the field.

```cs
    var logonTrigger = (ILogonTrigger) taskDef.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON);
    logonTrigger.UserId = Environment.UserName;
```

Comment: Well, will you deploy the app to a computer not joined to the domain?

Comment: Camilo, my app will be deployed to hundreds of clients - so I don't know if so, and that's my concern. That's why I posted this question.